# My new folder menu is creating a new shortcut, not a folder in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

when I use the new folder menu option it brings up the dialog for a new shortcut.
I have searched for a solution and cannot find one. I cannot create new folders now and have to resort to copying an existing blank folder and renaming it. The new folder option is on the right click, but it just creates a new shortcut, not a folder

Comment: Did you install anything new just before this happened? Does ctrl-shift-N create a new folder (as it should)?

Comment: Does the `cmd` command `md` (or `mkdir`) work?

Comment: I cant recall when it happened. I only noticed it recently. If I use ctrl shift n it brings up the new shortcut dialog box as well

Comment: yes md works fine

Comment: What does the "New"->"Shortcut" item do?

Comment: I have no idea if this works, but the title of the article seems to me to maybe describe what you might need to do, if you do not want to keep anything else on the Explorer context menu: [How To Reset Context Menu In Windows 10](http://windowsclan.com/how-to-reset-context-menu-in-windows-10/). If it goes wrong you might have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: it opens the create shortcut dialog box.

Comment: when I try to incorporate the reg file it says it is not a reg script.

Comment: If not work with new user account as what i recommanded, please use Process monitor to capture the system events during reproducing this issue, then upload the saved PML file for our research.

Answer (score 0):

The context registry key is under User configuration, the New user account on this PC would be fixed on this issue.

If so, please repair this corrupted user profile by this guide: https://www.techbout.com/fix-corrupt-user-profile-windows-10-9139/

Comment: Creating a new account does nothing, it still creates a new shortcut instead of folder. As a guess the problem appears to be with the registry key that deals with the new folder being the same as new shortcut, I just need to try and find out where those keys are and what needs changing I think

Comment: no creating a new user account did not solve the problem. Neither did repairing the corrupt account. It was definitely a registry issue as far as I could see.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have fixed the problem by doing a reset on my PC, it took a while but I can now create new folders.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem. I found the solution from other forum (thewindowsclub) like this.
The problem is that in registry key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew there were some keys that should not be there:

```
Handler "{ceefea1b-3e29-4ef1-b34c-fec79c4f70af}"
NullFile ""
```

The first one was causing the problem (creates a New Link). When I renamed the first one to "Handler2" it started to create an empty file instead. So I renamed the second one to NullFile2 and it started working to create a new directory/folder!